# Spring Boot Test with Cucumber and Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I recently started to use Cucumber to implement a set of behavior driven tests for a Java project based on Spring Boot. I would like to call REST endpoints of this application using something like [REST Assured](https://rest-assured.io/) or a custom REST client and for external systems and database I would like to setup some mock with Mockito, as I have already done with unit tests.

But I didn't find a complete working solution that I can apply to use Mockito beans in my Cucumber steps, for example to simulate a possible response from database queries.

I found a lot of posts of people over the years that had similar problems with different versions of Cucumber/Junit/Spring but I don't understand if it exists a right way to make these tools working together because I didn't a single complete example related to these tools together. Can anyone share experiences (versions/examples) in real world projects using Spring Boot Test, Cucumber and Mockito?

Comment: It's possible but `@MockBean` annotations are only picked up from the class annotated with `@CucumberContextConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. You can start the Cucumber test suite with a class like this

```
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("bdd")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, 
                        value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, 
                        value = "usage")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, 
                        value = "html:target/cucumber-reports")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, 
                        value = "myproject.cucumber.glue")
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

In the **glue** folder you can create a Spring Boot Test that will create the Spring Context and create the bridge between Spring Boot and Cucumber worlds thanks to **CucumberContextConfiguration**

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import myproject.repository.MyEntityRepository;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SpringBootTestStarter {

@MockBean
private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

}
```

Here you can use Mockito MockBean annotation and in the steps related to Cucumber scenarios you can now use this bean as a mock